# How to ship simple products of Group Product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, simple-product, grouped-products, associate-products

I am working on a web store where I want to add all associated products of group product to cart as whole. Like we do using Bundle Product. I want to restrict the user not to change the quantity or selection of the products. I hope my question is clear :)
If not let me know in comments I will let you understand. So you can help me.

Happy Learning!

Comment: Why don't you use Bundle Product?

Comment: I want to make a table containing the information about the simple products. And customizing the default layout of bundle product detail page is difficult for me :(